# Can't resolve all parameters for LoginPage: ([object Object], ?)

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic Framework: 3.9.2

LoginPage:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { AuthProvider } from "../../providers/auth/auth";
import { HomePage } from "../home/home";

@Component({
selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public authProvider: AuthProvider) {
  }

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    login: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
  });

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.authProvider.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(res => {
      if (res === 200) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

AuthProvider contain auth methods uses API. Its floating problem. Sometimes all work, but often display this error.

*EDIT*

AuthProvider code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
    public isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private configUtilService: ConfigUtilService,
              private app:App) {
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }

  get navCtrl(): NavController {
    console.log(this.app.getRootNav());
    return this.app.getRootNav();
  }

  public checkLogin(): Observable<number> {
    // rest request
  }

  login(data: any): Observable<number> {
    // rest request
  }


  sessionEnd(): Observable<number> {
    // rest request
  }

  refreshSession() {
    this.checkLogin().subscribe(() => {
    })
  }

  startSessionTimer(){
    this.refreshSession();
  }
```

I remove restAPI requests, because its simple httpClien requests with return login information from server

Comment: post the code for your authprovider

Comment: Is `AuthProvider` in the providers array in an appropriate module, like the app module?

Comment: Where is AuthProvider set as provider?

Comment: Yes, app.module.ts contain this provider in array

Comment: Can you add AuthProvider code to question?

Comment: Auth provider to long, i cant paste it here

Comment: post part of your code, not the logic

Comment: Is your ConfigService also in your module's providers?

Comment: David, yes i add my ConfigService in app.module

Comment: In _any_ of your providers, have you imported a page/component?

Comment: Yes, import HomePage, need it for redirect after auth

Comment: And what does your config ConfigUtilService depend on? Double check that you don't have a circular dependency somewhere

Comment: David, this service get data from json files and return it

Comment: I think this problem in my try to use NavConroller setRoot my HomePage component

Comment: Looks the issue is cyclic dependency somewhere.. You should avoid importing components in providers

Comment: Problem solved! I remove all components from providers and set redirect after method from service return data to component. Thanks all!

Comment: You can add as answer and close it

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with where you are providing the `AuthProvider` service. Make sure that the service is either provided in the `app.module` or in the module that contains the declaration of the `LoginPage` component.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by removing all component import in services/providers. Next time avoid this